# Connection timeout on query on large table

Tags: c#, mysql, timeout

I have a problem with a script timing out while fetching data form a query on large table.

The table have 9,521,457 rows.

The query I'm trying to preform is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `dialhistory` 
WHERE `customerId` IN (22606536, 22707251, 41598836);
```

This query runs without problems on HeidiSQL and take about 171 seconds and returns 434 rows.

But when I run my C# script dose it timeout after 161 rows.

```
16:54:55: Row 1
...
16:54:55: Row 161
16:55:32: Error -> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

Here is the code

```
public MySqlDatabase(string server, string database, string username, string password)
{
    ConnectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";DATABASE=" + database + ";UID=" + username + ";PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

}

public IQueryable<DailHistory> GetHistory(IList<int> customerIds)
{
    IList<DailHistory> list = new List<DailHistory>();
    var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `dialhistory` WHERE `customerId` in ("+string.Join(",", customerIds.ToArray())+")";
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    int i = 1;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": Row " + i);
        i++;
        try
        {
            var d = new DailHistory();
            d.CustomerId = int.Parse((string) reader["customerId"]);
            d.Agent = ParseNullAbleString(reader["agent"].ToString());
            d.CallBackReason = ParseNullAbleString(reader["callBackReason"].ToString());
            d.CallState = ParseCallSate(reader["callState"].ToString());
            d.ContactResponse = ParseNullAbleString(reader["contactResponse"].ToString());
            d.DailTime = new DailTime(reader["dialStart"].ToString(), reader["dialEnd"].ToString());
            d.HistoryIndex = int.Parse(reader["historyIndex"].ToString());
            d.Note = ParseNullAbleString(reader["note"].ToString());
            d.OldDialNo = ParseNullAbleInt(reader["oldDialNo"].ToString());
            d.ProjectJob = ParseNullAbleString(reader["projectJob"].ToString());
            list.Add(d);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    return list.AsQueryable();
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
command.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;
```

If you know more exactly which number to insert, do that. If you set it to `int.MaxValue`, you are removing a security barrier.

Answer (score 12):

Set the [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28VS.80%29.aspx) on the command object

```
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandTimeout = 0;
//zero specifies never timeout. 
//Any number greater than zero is the number of seconds before 
//the command will time out.
```

Comment: command.CommandTimeout = 0; did not work :( it still timed out

Comment: @DoomStone Your database can have a timeout defined, when you request the timeout using commandTimeout this can be overriden by database configuration. In my case it worked for me, but in your case it might be an issue you need to work out with your DBA.. (for future readers.. obviously your issue was years ago sorry)

Answer (score 2):

Add an index on the `customerId` column.

Comment: There are, it is the primary key!

Comment: @DoomStone - I don't see how it can possibly take 171 secs to return 434 rows then. Are you returning some extremely wide data (e.g. BLOBs) And `CustomerId` can't be the PK on its own anyway if 3 customerids return 434 rows. What are the other columns in the index and what is the order of these columns in the composite index?

Comment: Did you mean this was the primary key for another table?  If it were the primary key on this table then you should not be getting 434 rows returned from your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
command.CommandTimeout = 2147483;
```

The largest value for a MySQL command timeout is the largest value for a 32 bit integer, in milliseconds, 2147483647. But in C# the CommandTimeout property is in seconds, not milliseconds, so any higher than 2147483 will result in an exception.

Although this is not infinite, it is 24 days, 20 hours, 31 minutes, and 23 seconds, which would hopefully meet your need.

Setting the value to 0 did not work for me. The CommandTimeout property would not retain the value of 0 and kept auto-changing back to 30.

Setting the value to -1 did seem to work, but I didn't test it enough to be certain that a timeout would never occur.

Safest option: go with 2147483.