# MySqlDataAdapter.Fill() is slow/fails

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable, dataadapter

I currently use the `MySQL.Data` extension in order to load my MySQL database information into my C# application. I use the `MySqlDataAdapter.Fill()` command to load the data into a `DataTable`. 
This solution works for the majority of my tables, except the larger ones. For example, I have a table that's about 1,310,634 rows long. When I attempt to fill a `DataTable` with that data, the application will hang and eventually fail with an exception:

> Exception was Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I've tried solutions where I increase the timeouts of the MySQL connection with commands like this `set net_write_timeout=99999; set net_read_timeout=99999;`, but it doesn't seem to help.

This is my C# code so far:

```
//Construct output DataTable
DataTable output = new DataTable();

MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection); 

try
{
    ad.FillSchema(output, SchemaType.Mapped); //Filling Columns, Types, Limitations
    ad.Fill(output); //Filling Data
    ad.Dispose();                
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ throw; }

return output;
```

Comment: The obvious question... Do you *really need* to load over a million rows into memory all at once?  (Also, note that your try/catch block is entirely superfluous.  You can simplify the code by just removing it.)

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315701/connection-timeout-on-query-on-large-table

Comment: @David Unfortunately, I'm working on a data sync type of application. It's necessary to load everything into memory. The weird thing I'm finding is that I'm only having timeout errors on machine running Windows 10 (no matter what the hardware). If I run the application on a Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, or Windows 8.1 machine, the application loads the tables without a problem or delay....

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments above, the best solution to your issue is to refactor your solution. Instead of fetching the whole tables from your database, use some SQL SELECT-statements to get only the rows you really need to accomplish the task at hand.

If you really need to process the whole table, e.g. for some kind of consistency check that cannot be accomplished with SQL, then you could load the data in portions, selecting only 100K rows at a time.

But again, I doubt fetching multiple tables with over a million rows at the same time is a valid use case and therefore should not be performed...